# checkbox type in form

Tags: 7, forms

how i can knowing if the checkbox is checked or not on the form

```
function darksite_config_page() {
  $form['darksite_status'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Enable pop up screen'),
    '#description' => t('When enabled, a pop up screen will be displayed on the home page.'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('darksite_status', 0)
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Comment: check can be done in $form_state variable

Comment: where are you trying to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
if (variable_get('darksite_status', 0)) {
  // Yes.
}
else {
  // No.
}
```